# How to remove logo from product swatch images in product detail page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-images, frontend, magento2.3.4

I am getting one issue on the product detail page. I have created the configurable product and added the color swatches with images. when I visit the product detail page of those products.

I can see the product images but the transparent website logo is adding on it. Even I don't have the placeholders and any default thumbnails.

**How to remove the logo from it**

Please find the below image. Any solution for this please let me know if anyone facing this issue

[image]

Comment: I believe there you can specify if images should contain a watermark in the admin panel but i  dont have any instance to check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Admin->Content->Design->Configuration->Edit Your Theme**

And **remove the Images** from **Product Image Watermarks**

Save the settings, **Clean cache** and **Flush Catalog Image cache** from **Additional Cache Management** in **System->Cache Management**

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I tried all these things as well. My current version 2.3.4., I am assuming this is an issue with the newly released version. If anyone having the issue please let me know

Comment: Have you removed the watermark images from all the stores?

Comment: I haven't added any watermark images and removed theme images, favicon etc...! I removed that product and again created whenever I tried to create this color configurable product getting the same image watermarks and adding as a layer on the images and it was fixed to that image

Comment: This is worked form me. I was added to a different store, I just forgot and it was my mistake. Thank you so much to get me to look into it . I just accepted your answer as my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I have check the your web site and see the issues.

And i have find the solution.

This is not a issue.This simple image image problem Please check screen-short :-

[image]

Image path open the new tab and see the image. images showing are this type.

[image]

This image product image and transparent logo is not different. it is same one image.so you can not remove the transparent logo.

And want to must be remove the transparent logo. As Download the product images and open the photoshop and remove the transparent background

Comment: I have gone through it for the same, But I uploaded without any logo transperant logo image. It is happening for color swatches of configurable products. I wondered it was embedded in the main image.